# Django global variable for base.html

Tags: django, variables, global

I've implemented a global variable, but I don't really know how to access it. The examples I have found are a bit confusing.

**models.py**

```
...
# Categorys of Post Model
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Title")
   

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

#Post Model
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

...
```

**settings.py:**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.core.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"Post.global.category_dropdown",
)
```

**global.py**

```
from .models import Category

def category_dropdown(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return {'categories': categories}
```

**base.html:**

```
<body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <form method="POST">
            <label>
                <select name="Category">
                    {% for global in category_dropdown %}
                        <option value="{{ categorie.title }}">{{ categorie.title }} {{ categorie.post_set.count }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </label>
        </form>
```

1. I'm not really sure if its implemented the right way.
2. I don't know how to access the global var. in Template

In the end this should display a dropdown menu in the header of every page which gets his value from the database as you can see in models.py

thanks in advance

Comment: Template tag or context processor.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT:

I see what you want. I think you are very close to a solution, and what you found is very similar to my previous answer. The main difference is, that you inject context in a `global.py` file with `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR`.

So with `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` you inject the context variables in your context dictionary. For example, if you have Form then your context looks like:

```
{ 
  'form': {
  ...
  }
}
```

in your case you always inject the parameter **`categories`** inside so your context looks like:

```
{ 
  'form': {
  ...
  },
  'categories': [
        {
          'title': 'your title 1'
          'posts': [...]
        },
        {
          'title': 'your title 2'
          'posts': [...]
        },
        ....
   ]
}
```

So what you could do is access this context variable inside your HTML code.

```
<body>
  <div class="page-header">
    <form method="POST">
      <label>
        <select name="Category">
          {% for category in categories %}
            <option value="{{ category.title }}">{{ category.title }} {{ category.post_set.count }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </label>
    </form>
```

Because the name of the variable in dictionary is '***category***', (and contains array of your categories) you should access this variable in your for loop. When you iterate trough categories you create temporary variable named ***category*** (or any other name) and use this variable to access title and number of posts.

### PREVIOUS:

I am not sure what you are asking for.

But what you probably need is to have category list always inside your `context_data`.

This mean that you can prepare some function that fetch all Category and create context from it like :

```
def prepare_category_context(context_data):
    """
    Function that create context data for all Views classes. 
    """
    context_data['categories'] = model.Category.objects.all()
    return  context_data


class myView(generic.EnyViewClass):
    """
    Example of the View Class. This could be generic.TemplateView, CreateView,...
    The trick is to add context data inside class.
    """

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Here we defined context data that will be used in templates.
        We call our function here. But we need to call super first, if we have some form data or any thing else already in context...
        """
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context = self.prepare_category_context(context)
        return context
```

Comment: Take a look at this:

http://blog.khmelyuk.com/2011/10/django-use-global-variables-on.html

This is what i need but i dont know how to propperly implement it, an example would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented something similar, but I used session in the context processor, I don't know if it's the best option but it seemed functional, I hope it can help someone.

Note: In my case, the categories do not come from a table but from options since in this case I handle few. I think it would be to adjust a bit with the Category model

**context_processors.py**

```
def set_or_get_category_option(request):
    # get from session category selection or default
    if "category_option" in request.session:
        category = request.session["category_option"]
        return {"category": category}
    else:
        request.session["category_option"] = "your_default_category"
        return {"category": "your_default_category"}
```

**utils.py**

```
def check_category_from_session(request):
    post_category = request.POST.get("category", None)
    if post_category:
        # Set category in session
        for key, value in CategoryOptions.choices:
        if gender == value:
            if key == 1:
                request.session["category_option"] = "one"
            elif key == 2:
                request.session["category_option"] = "two"
            .
            .
            return key
    
    # Check category from request session
    if request.session["category_option"]:
        if request.session["category_option"] == "one":
            return CategoryOptions.ONE
        elif request.session["category_option"] == "two":
            return CategoryOptions.TWO
        .
        .
    return None
```

**index_view.py**

```
# Django
from django.shortcuts import render

# Models
from ..models import Product

# Utils
from .utils import check_category_from_session


def index_view(request):
    # Check category
    category_choice = check_category_from_session(request)
    if category_choice:
        products = (
                Product.objects.filter(category=category_choice)
                .order_by("?")[:36]
            )
    else:
        products = Product.objects.order_by("?")[:36] # or by default


    # Render template
    return render(
        request,
        template_name="index.html",
        context={
            "products": products,
        },
    )
```

**base.html**

```
<form name="setcategory" class="select-wrapper" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="category" />
    <div class="select-default">
        {% if category == "one" %}
        <button>CAT 1</button>
        {% elif category == "two" %}
        <button>CAT 2</button>
        {% else %}
        <button>All products</button>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div name="category" class="select-options" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <button type="button" class="select-option" value="one" data-name="Cat 1" onclick="document.setcategory.category.value='one';
        document.setcategory.submit();">
            CAT 1
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="select-option" value="two" data-name="Cat 2" onclick="document.setcategory.category.value='two';
        document.setcategory.submit();">
            CAT 2
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```