# Display tasks count in base.html

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a Task model and in my base template I want to display the number of tasks and a list of the tasks.

How can I do this without having to import the Task model manually through my context dictionary in every view?

Right now I have this:

**base.html**

```
<span class="notification">{{tasks.count}}</span>
```

**views.py**

```
def dashboard_view(request):
    context = {
        "tasks": Task.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name='main/index.html', context=context)
```

As one might imagine, having this in every view night not be practical.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586616/django-global-variable-for-base-html this may be what your lookin for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a [*context processor* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext). For example in a certain app you can write:

```
# app/context_processors.py

def task_count(request):
    from app.models import Task
    return {
        'tasks': Task.objects.all()
    }
```

then you can register this context processor in the `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py

# …

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # …
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # …
                'app.context_processors.task_count'
            ]
        }
        # …
    }
]
```

For every template you render, it will thus make a variable `tasks` available, that will contain a `QuerySet` with all tasks. Since `QuerySet`s are lazy, it will not execute the query if you do not need it.

Comment: Awesome thanks for your reply! I only need the task model in one app. How does it know if I need it?

Comment: @GTA.sprx: it does not matter, if you do not mention `{{ tasks.count }}` (or `{% for ... in tasks %}` or something else with `tasks) in the template, it will simply not execute the database query.

Comment: That's convenient!